# Counting characters in Python

Tags: python, character, counting

I am trying to write this program, which would tell me what's written in a text file and would also count the characters in that file. But I am stuck on the counting part. Here is my code.

```
def read_file(filename):
    infile = open(filename)
    
    
    for line in infile:
        print (line, end = "")
    print()
    
    print("There are",len(line),"letters in the file")
    
    infile.close()
```

here is the output:

```
Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall,
Humpty Dumpty had a great fall.
All the king's horses and all the king's men
Couldn't put Humpty together again.
There are 35 letters in the file
```

The issue is its count the words as a whole and not characters. It should have said "There are 141 letters in the file" but it says 35. What am I doing wrong??

P.S  I am using Python 3.9.7

Comment: You're just counting the characters of the last line, not the whole text. Also be careful, the newlines are eventually counted as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

35 isn't the number of words in the file, it's the number of characters in the last `line`:

```
>>> len("Couldn't put Humpty together again.")
35
```

If you want to sum *all* the lengths of *all* the lines you'll want to do it in your loop:

```
    file_len = 0 
    for line in infile:
        print(line, end = "")
        file_len += len(line)
    print()

    print(f"There are {file_len} letters in the file")
```

Note that there's a difference between `len(line)` (the raw character count which includes punctuation, whitespace, etc) and the number of *letters* in the line:

```
>>> sum(c.isalpha() for c in "Couldn't put Humpty together again.")
29
```

Comment: This will be incorrect if you don't account for the newline characters

Comment: Counting newline characters isn't necessarily incorrect -- but if you're trying to count the **number of letters**, newlines aren't the only characters you need to exclude!